# Are there any unwanted gnome libraries for a unity user?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome

My /usr volume has run out of space. Are there any libraries from gnome that is safe to remove. I am using unity and I don't think I will need to use 'Ubuntu classic' again.

I used apt-get autoremove and clean, but there were no unused libraries. Are there any apps that might not be needed?

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Unity is a shell for Gnome you still need about all of the Gnome stack. Removing metacity and gnome-panel should be safe, but that doesn't free up much space.

Comment: I'd even keep those around - I still like me 'ol `gnome-panel`

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you asked such a question as it gives a chance to clear up some things.

Unity may not directly use GNOME libraries, but the **experience** provided by Unity depends upon the GNOME platform. If you ran out of space in `/usr`, then it is likely that you installed too many applications/libraries, and it's time to do an audit.

What I would suggest is looking for any libraries/applications that are auto-removable, and then looking for the applications you use least.